# Play Framework 2.5.9 Scala handling multipart/form-data file field allways Some

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm following documentation from here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFileUpload to handle file upload in form. 
My code is here:

```
  def add(method: String) = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
    if (method == "GET") {
      Ok(views.html.add(uploadForm))
    } else {
      uploadForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
        hasErrors => BadRequest(views.html.add(hasErrors)),
        form => {
          Logger.debug(request.body.file("myfilefield").toString)
          Ok(views.html.add(uploadForm))
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

Whenever I submit this form, even if I didn't select file in file field I'm getting something like this in console:

> [debug] application -
>   Some(FilePart(myfilefield,,Some(application/octet-stream),TemporaryFile(/var/folders/n3/8nrp7hw94bqbsjbcz00n5hk40000gn/T/playtemp4371116121043398878/multipartBody1548294152084205009asTemporaryFile)))

I can't understand why is this so. I think there are should be None in `request.body.file("myfilefield")` if I didn't select file before submitting form.
How can I find if file was submitted?

Ok. Now I just copied code from documentation and got the same result :( 
Here is my controller action:

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
    import java.io.File
    val filename = picture.filename
    val contentType = picture.contentType
    picture.ref.moveTo(new File(s"/tmp/picture/$filename"))
    Ok("File uploaded")
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.HomeController.uploadtest()).flashing(
      "error" -> "Missing file")
  }
}
```

and here is my view:

> @()
>
> ```
> @helper.form(action = routes.HomeController.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
>
>     <input type="file" name="picture">
>
>     <p>
>         <input type="submit">
>     </p>
>
> }
> ```

Whenever I submit this form I got "File uploaded" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this is a bug: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6203